# What's the `x_budle-g2-g1.crt` in Apache certificate directory?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

I applied the Apache certificates from Goddady, in the directory there have:

[image]

I checked them, the `x.crt` content is as the same as `x.pem`(only one `CERTIFICATE`), the `x_bundle-g2-g1.crt` has 3 `CERTIFICATE` in it.

Why there need the same content `x.crt` and `x.pem`?
What's the function of `x_bundle-g2-g1.crt`, where there have 3 `CERTIFICATE`, whether them refer to `x_bundle`, `g2` and `g1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that `X.pem` is your server certificate, and it is issued by GoDaddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2

Then `x_bundle-g2-g1.crt` is the chain of trust till the root GoDaddy certificate.

Check the contents of `x_bundle-g2-g1.crt` using openssl command:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile x_bundle-g2-g1.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout | grep -E 'Subject:|Issuer:'
```

*This hack is to print all certificates in PEM file*

I expect the output would be like this:

```
        Issuer: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
        Subject: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
        Issuer: C=US, O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc., OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
        Subject: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
        Issuer: C=US, O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc., OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
        Subject: C=US, O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc., OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
```

That is,

1. `Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2` signed by `Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2`
2. `Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2`
3. self-signed `Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority`

Check which certificates your web server provides to the client:
`openssl s_client -showcerts -servername YOUR_SERVER -connect YOUR_SERVER:443 </dev/null`

I'd bet that it provides the complete chain -

- your server certificate from `X.pem`
- Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
- Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2

This is a precaution for end systems, such as brosers, that miss intermediate GoDaddy certificate.

Comment: Yes gd_bundle-g2-g1 is a standard file containing the G2 intermediate (for SSL/TLS) aka gdig2, the G2-to-G1-cross and the G1 root. See https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository under the heading 'GoDaddy Certificate Chain - G2' and for the G2 cross and G1 root the heading 'GoDaddy Certificate Chain' (with no G). For most nonobsolete clients you can instead use gd_bundle-g2 which contains gdroot-g2 which is the real G2 root (no cross to G1).

Comment: Your response helped me a lot, but why there have two files(`76392976b464dce.crt` and `76392976b464dce.pem`) have the same content? why not one file?